# Update possibly needed to 'tag edit review'

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, rejection-reasons

I had my first ever suggested tag edit come through my review queue today - yay-

During my rejection of the tag edit suggestion I noticed that some of the reasons seem a little out of place for tags and would more be suited to a question or answer. The first most noticable would be the constant use of the word post. Should this not be changed to tag?

The second would be the invalid edit. Why does it have something in there about about replying to a coment on a previous post.

It seems almost as a few of the rejection reasons for a edit to answers and questions have made it across into tag reviews.

[image]